# Struct Problems in C

Tags: c, struct

I have the following struct

```
typedef struct rotor {
    char characters[26];
    char* rotationPos;
    char* aPosition;
} rotor;
```

and I want to create 3 instances of it like this:

```
char cadeia3[26] = "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO";
char cadeia2[26] = "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE";
char cadeia1[26] = "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ";

rotor* r1;
rotor* r2;
rotor* r3;
r1 = createRotor(cadeia1, 20);
r2 = createRotor(cadeia2, 20);
r3 = createRotor(cadeia3, 20);
```

The `createRotor` function automatically creates a rotor:

```
rotor* createRotor(char* cadeia, char* c) {
    int aux;
    rotor* r;
    for (aux = 0; aux < 26; aux++) {
        if (cadeia[aux] == NULL || strlen(cadeia) > 26) {
            return -1;
        } else
            r->characters[aux] = cadeia[aux];
    }
    r->characters[26] = '\0';
    r->rotationPos = c;
    r->aPosition = r->characters[0];
    return r;
}
```

This only works for the first rotor... Whenever I want to verify the content or use in a function any of the other ones the program is "terminated". To me the strange thing is working for one perfectly and not for the others.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you passing a value of `20` in for a `char *c` argument?

Comment: To me, the strange thing is that it works at all.  As diagnosed by [amit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/572670/amit) in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23376410/15168), you are not allocating space for the rotor, so it is amazing it doesn't crash on the first invocation (or you have bad luck that it doesn't crash then).  But that's the trouble with undefined behaviour: you can't predict what's going to happen. You also need to pay more attention to the compiler warnings; there are all sorts of things that it should tell you about. Remember, the compiler knows more about C than you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like undefined behavior to me.

You are not allocating (dynamically) the memory needed to `rotor` anywhere. Your `createRotor()` function just stores data in some random junk address (that is the value of `r`), and you try to access it. You never initialize `r` to an address allocated for your program.

Answer (score 2):

```
 char cadeia3[26] = "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO";
```

the string literal is already 26 characters long, which means there is no room for the null terminator in the array. So this call:

```
 strlen(cadeia);
```

will invoke undefined behavior.

Use:

```
 char cadeia3[27] = "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO";
```

or

```
 char cadeia3[] = "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO";
```

Comment: but the array goes from [0] to [26], 27 positions right?

Comment: @MMrj - _but the array goes from [0] to [26], 27 positions right?_ Yes.  Array[n] index values are always from 0 to n-1 (or in this case 0 to 26)

Answer (score 0):

Three suggested changes:

1) If you're using a byte constant (like "20"), define the parameter as "char c", not "char *c":

```
rotor* createRotor(char* cadeia, char* c)
```

2) More important, if your string is 26 letters long ... then the character array must be (at least) 27 characters:

```
typedef struct rotor {
    char characters[27];
    char* rotationPos;
    char* aPosition;
} rotor;
...
char cadeia3[27] = "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO";
```

3) Most important, make sure you *ALLOCATE* each of your "rotor" structs somewhere.